# How do I find the parameters used in kmeans to create clusters?

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis

From a previous [question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-April/031666.html) on the R-list, I saw two approaches for examining packages that are loaded in:

```
ls("package:ts") 
lsf.str("package:ts")
```

In my case, I want to examine what the output of `kmeans` is, which is a function in the `stats` package, so I used:

```
lsf.str("package:stats")
```

However, I don't know how to examine what is returned from this command. I want to identify the parameters used in a previous clustering, so that I can apply them to another dataset. Where I can find the parameters that are stored as part of this function?

Comment: If you want to know what a function does and what it returns, look at it's help page `?kmeans`. If you want to look at the source code, then just run `kmeans` (without parentheses) at the prompt - which will show a version of the code (no comments etc). If you want to inspect the object returned by `kmeans()`, run the example: `example(kmeans)` and then do `str(cl)` and `names(cl)`. But by the sounds of it, I don't think this will help any - you seem to suggest you want to predict which clusters the new dataset would fall into and you can't do that using `kmeans()` Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Ah, I see; thanks for your explanation. How do you see the source code with comments?

Comment: if there are any, then it will be in the R source tarball or in the svn repository https://svn.r-project.org/R/ e.g.: http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/kmeans.R but in this case there aren't any of note to explain what the code does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Value* section of the `kmeans` help page lists the format of the object returned byt he function :

> An object of class ‘"kmeans"’ which has a ‘print’ method and is a
>        list with components:
>
> cluster: A vector of integers (from
>   ‘1:k’) indicating the cluster to
>             which each point is allocated.
>
> centers: A matrix of cluster centres.
>
> withinss: The within-cluster sum of
>   squares for each cluster.
>
> totss: The total within-cluster sum
>   of squares.
>
> tot.withinss: Total within-cluster sum
>   of squares, i.e.,
>             ‘sum(withinss)’.
>
> betweenss: The between-cluster sum of
>   squares.
>
> size: The number of points in each cluster.

In general you can also list these values directly from your `kmeans` object with the `names` function :

```
R> names(km)
[1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"    
[5] "tot.withinss" "betweenss"    "size"
```

From the description of the values in the help page, I would say that the parameters used for the clustering are not stored in the resulting object. So if you only have access to the resulting `kmeans` object and not to the original function call, I would say that these parameters are lost, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

If you type in `kmeans` you'll get the sourcecode of the method, available in pastebin at http://pastebin.com/6VnnhU7J .  I'm not sure what you mean about the parameters as those are passed in as arguments (x, centers, iter.max = 10, nstart = 1, algorithm = c("Hartigan-Wong", "Lloyd", "Forgy", "MacQueen") and you have easy access to them (what did you call kmeans with originally?)

Comment: I originally called `kmeans` as follows: `fit <- kmeans(mydata, 3)`. I was hoping that I could apply the same criteria to another data set to produce more clusters (for example, if this was a tree-sorting algorithm, I could say all values < 0.5 are in cluster 1, etc.).

Comment: I guess you could take the `centers` component of the fit, and compute the Euclidean distance between your new data points and the identified cluster centres, and assign each data point to the nearest cluster centre? But note, this need not be the same result as you would have gotten if you'd clustered all the data (old and new) in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps I'm moving into New Question territory with this comment, but is this a good approach? I'm quite new to clustering in general, and am not sure what the best way of doing this is.

Comment: @celenius It is a practical approach, and one that is adopted in at least one CRAN package (**cclust**) - so you could run your k-means with the `cclust()` function and use its `predict()` method so avoiding doing this by hand. How useful this is and whether there are better ways depends really on what you want to do and here is not the place for that discussion. Try http://stats.stackexchange.com You seem to want to do both clustering **and** classification.

Comment: @celenius also, if you want to comment on a comment by someone who isn't the original poster of the Answer, make sure you start your comment with `@foo` where `foo` is the user name, e.g. to reply to me, start it with @Gavin. That way the person who wrote the comment gets a note in their inbox --- I would have missed your comment if I hadn't have been browsing the answers again.

Comment: @Gavin - I forgot to include the `@`! Thanks for all your help; I'll explore `cclust()`